# Using passed var in helper with meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to use a template for all media elements in my Meteor site. I will build some conditions in to handle audio and video. I want to be able to pass through a "store" for use in the images. If I include this currently, it works using this

```
{{> recordMedia}}
```

What I want to be able to do is something like this

```
{{> recordMedia store="thumb"}}
```

The value of store needs to be used in the **VARHERE** part of the code below. How do I do this?

```
<template name="recordMedia">
    {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
        {{#if media}}
            {{#each media}}
                {{#if isImage}}
                    <img src="{{this.url store='VAR HERE'}}" class="full">
                {{/if}}
            {{/each}}
        {{ else }}
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/ffffff.png&text=No+Media" class="full">
        {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you just reference it from the parent.  Passing named args into a template sets the templates data context to those args. You're also using an each block which sets the data context inside of the block to your `media`, so the args are available on `../`

```
<template name="recordMedia">
    {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
        {{#if media}}
            {{#each media}}
                {{#if isImage}}
                    <img src="{{this.url store=../store}}" class="full">
                {{/if}}
            {{/each}}
        {{ else }}
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/ffffff.png&text=No+Media" class="full">
        {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
</template>
```